# Optimize Arraylist function call

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the following to retrieve some user info based on IP address. `ClientLocation()` returns an array with city, state and coordinates.

My concern with this is the function is called whenever I want to retrieve different array values. How can this be optimized so that the function is called once, but still retrieve multiple array values.

```
Public Function ClientLocation() As Object

    Dim Result As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim XMLDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    Dim APIKey = "apikey"
    Dim GetXML = "url in xml"

    Try
        XMLDoc.Load(GetXML)
        Dim XMLResponse As XmlNodeList = XMLDoc.SelectNodes("Response")
        For Each Item As XmlNode In XMLResponse
            Result.Add(Item("cityName").InnerText & ", " & Item("regionName").InnerText)
            Result.Add(Item("latitude").InnerText & "," & Item("longitude").InnerText)
            Return (Result)
        Next
    Catch err As Exception
        Result.Add("Not Available")
        Result.Add("Not Available")
        Return (Result)
    End Try

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Calling function

```
Dim UserProfile As ProfileCommon = Profile.GetProfile(User.Identity.Name)

UserProfile.Location = ClientLocation.Item(0)
UserProfile.Coordinates = ClientLocation.Item(1)
UserProfile.Save()
```

Comment: The function could return type ArrayList instead of type object. `Public Function ClientLocation() As ArrayList`. Then return the result into a local variable. `Dim a = ClientLocation()`. Then read the values `UserProfile.Location = a(0)` and `UserProfile.Coordinates = a(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an xml structure that would be similar to:

```
<Responses>
    <Response>
        <Item>
            <cityname>abc</cityname>
            <regionname>def</regionname>
            <latitude>101.2345</latitude>
            <longitude>34.3456</longitude>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <cityname>ghi</cityname>
            <regionname>jkl</regionname>
            <latitude>101.2345</latitude>
            <longitude>34.3456</longitude>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <cityname>mno</cityname>
            <regionname>pqr</regionname>
            <latitude>101.2345</latitude>
            <longitude>34.3456</longitude>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <cityname>stu</cityname>
            <regionname>vwx</regionname>
            <latitude>101.2345</latitude>
            <longitude>34.3456</longitude>
        </Item>
    </Response>
</Responses>
```

You could use the `XMLSerializer` class to deserialize the whole file all at once, by creating a class to contain the data:

```
Public Class Responses
    Public Class Item
        Dim cityname As String = ""
        Dim regionname As String = ""
        Dim latitude As Double = 0.0
        Dim longitude As Double = 0.0
    End Class
    <XmlArrayAttribute("Response")>
    Dim items As New List(Of Item)
End Class
```

Getting the data would be as simple as:

```
XMLDoc.Load(GetXML)
Dim result As Responses = CType(New XmlSerializer(GetType(Responses)) _
.Deserialize(New StringReader(XMLDoc.OuterXml)), Responses)
```

You would access the data through the `items` field of `result`:

```
result.items(0).cityname
```